# Why is the nav class name navbar-default and not navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, class, border, navbar

I'm learning coding in Ruby on Rails and I'm making a random web page. I have added bootstrap navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
```

I am trying to change the border of the navbar to none but instead of :

```
.navbar {
   border: 0;
}
```

I have to use :

```
.navbar-default {
   border: 0;
}
```

This is my code:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class='container'>
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">DevMatch</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: The only way I managed to set the .navbar {border: 0;} is to remove the navbar-default class from my nav element . Why ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following, and to make sure your style will be applied, please add the !important.

```
.navbar { border: none !important; }
```

Comment: O also learned that CSS specificity had everything to do with my issue . Apparently the border of nav was taken from .navbar navbar-default .

Answer (score 0):

Marius,

Yes, it does have to do with CSS specificity. I'd like to disagree with the previous answer of using `!important` to override a style. For a one-off change it might look convenient but over a period of time as your website grows, and you continue to use `!important` in multiple places, it may become really difficult to maintain.

To increase the weight of a given CSS declaration, I would suggest using multiple selectors instead. You could try something like -

```
nav.navbar {
   border: 0;
}
```

As you can see, adding the element along with the classname has more weight than just using the classname on its own.

[image]

More details on CSS specificity can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).